# Using "this", when function and selector are not together

Tags: javascript, jquery

With this

**example 1**

```
$("#my_div").on("click", function () {
    alert( $(this).attr("id") )
});
```

we obtain correct result, but if I use this:

**example 2**

```
function thisId () {
    alert( $(this).attr("id") )
}

$("#my_div").on("click", function () {
    thisId();
});
```

Now the result is undefined. Please tell me how I should be using `this`, when the selector and function using `this` are written as different expressions, as in **example 2**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For jQuery to pass the element reference to the function you must provide the function as a reference. Try this:

```
$("#my_div").on("click", thisId);
```

**Update for @bot**

```
function thisId (event) {
    alert( $(this).attr("id") )
    alert(event.type);
}

$("#my_div").on("click", thisId);
```

Comment: Could you also give an example of passing in the event?

Comment: @Bot the event would be passed in the exact same way as you define your anonymous function. See my update for the example.

Comment: Thanks, just trying to think ahead if anyone comes across this question and is looking for that specific answer.

Answer (score 2):

@RoryMcCrossan's answer is the correct one, here's why: JS determines what `this` references *ad hoc*, that is: when the function is called, it looks at the call-context:

```
myObject.property = function(){console.log(this)}
myObject.property();
  /\          ||
  ||who called |
  |_____________
```

If the function wasn't called as a method of an obeject, like you did with `thisId`, JS -like it always does- falls back to the global object, and `this` will point to `window`.
You can determine the calling context programmatically, with `functionName.call(context)` and `functionName.apply(context,[arguments]);`, which is what jQuery does behind the scenes:

```
$.fn.on(evt,callback)//simplified
{//jQ sets up its own event handler that looks like this:
    //here, this point to $("#my_div") in your case, so:
    var jQhandler = function(e)
    {
        callback.apply(this,[e]);//passes the event as an argument
    };
    this.addEventListener(evt,jQhandler,false);//<-- passes its handler by reference
}
```

So you can do either this use apply, which -in your case- requires yet another anon. function object to be created, or pass the function directly to jQuery as being the callback. The latter being far more efficient: less verbose and less function objects required.

This is, in short, why @RoryMcCrossan is correct, and why some consider JS to be the worlds most misunderstood language: the bulk of ppl using it don't really know about how JS determines the context.

---

Just as a side-note: ECMA5 allows you to bind a function to a context, using the `.bind` method, but that would take us to far off-topic...